# Insert values into one table from form and other multiple other tables

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a form that has three inputs. Two dropdowns and a text input. The dropdowns are populated from my database before they're displayed. The text input is new data from the user. The user will add a new asset to my database but will have to choose the item's manufacturer and category.

Once the asset is added I want the asset table to be updated. I am stuck on how INSERT INTO my asset_names table using both form data and the existing values from the dropdowns. I need to take the values, user-friendly words, and select their corresponding IDs from their respective databases.

```
INSERT INTO asset_names (asset_name, asset_category_id, asset_manufacturer_id, asset_status_id)
VALUES ( :newAssetName,
        ( SELECT category_id FROM asset_categories WHERE category_name=:newAssetCategory),
        ( SELECT manufacturer_id FROM manufacturers WHERE name=:newAssetManufacturer),
        1)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $sql );

//Bind value.
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetName',     $newAssetName  );
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetCategory', $newAssetCategory );
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetManufacturer', $newAssetManufacturer );


//Execute.
$stmt->execute();
```

If I hardcode values into the statement variables then the statement works. It is almost as if the variables are null now.

Comment: `:newAssetManufacture` != `:newAssetManufacturer`.

Comment: @chris85, I fixed that typo.

Comment: Okay, so what happens with this code now? It throws an error? Inserts the wrong data? Why have the subqueries, just put the id's as the value of the `option` in the form.

Comment: @chris85, what happens is that when I submit the form the fields are inserted into the database but the values the variables, :newAssetCategory and :newAssetManufacturer, are entered as 0. I am not sure where the 0 came from. I'm using the select statements because I need to take the strings from the dropdowns and use them to find their respective row ID. I've made the table keys based off of auto-incrementing row IDs.

Comment: Why do you need the values to be strings and not integers?

Comment: That's what they are in the dropdown menu so I thought I'd just use the text value from the dropdown and then search tables based on that.

Comment: I feel like there is an issue with using nested subqueries and prepared statement variables in this.

Comment: @chris85, that worked perfectly. I thought it'd be better to do it all with an SQL query all at once.

Comment: Great, I've posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use subqueries. Just pass the data to the DOM.

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $stringversion;?></option>
```

then you can just bind the value as expected.

```
"INSERT INTO asset_names (asset_name, asset_category_id, asset_manufacturer_id, asset_status_id)
VALUES ( :newAssetName,
        :newAssetCategory),
        :newAssetManufacturer),
        1)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
//Bind value.
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetName', $newAssetName  );
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetCategory', $newAssetCategory );
$stmt->bindValue( ':newAssetManufacturer', $newAssetManufacturer );
```